# MySQL Query by Date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I change this MySQL query in PHP to only show all listings where a date column called OpenHouseDate in the database is the current day or forward?

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Comment: Not to mention http://www.paperplanes.de/2008/4/24/mysql_nonos_order_by_rand.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the OpenHouseDate is of 'Date' type then you can use the following:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE OpenHouseDate <= CURDATE();
```

If the OpenHouseDate is of 'DateTime' type then you can use the following:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE OpenHouseDate <= NOW();
```

If the OpenHouseDate is of 'Integer' type then you can use the following:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE OpenHouseDate <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

[MySQL Date/Time Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM listings where OpenHouseDate >= current_date ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE DATE(OpenHouseDate) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Order By clause will need to be moved to the end of the query

Comment: Thanks @AuthmanApatira, missed that!

Comment: I made the same mistake like 10 min ago, on a live sys noless =P